# What is 0xFF and why is it shifted 24 times?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

```
#define SwapByte4(ldata) \
   (((ldata & 0x000000FF) << 24) | \
   ((ldata & 0x0000FF00) << 8) | \
   ((ldata & 0x00FF0000) >> 8) | \
   ((ldata & 0xFF000000) >> 24))
```

What does that 0x000000FF represent?  I know that decimal 15 is represented in hex as F, but why is it << 24?

Comment: 1. you don't need the \ in the end of lines. 2. Do I smell homework? If so, please tag accordingly

Comment: @Armen: I suspect the start of the first line is "#define"; how would tagging [homework] help you better answer this question?

Comment: @Roger: It wouldn't. It is just a custom in SO to tag homework questions with the homework tag

Comment: @RogerPate, because a better answer to a homework question teaches the OP something. If it's just a technical question, providing the answer is enough. If it's homework, just provding the answer is probably not the best tihng to do.

Comment: @Paul: How does being assigned by a teacher change how the OP will best understand?

Comment: @Armen: You said exactly my point: it doesn't help.  Why add tags that don't help?

Comment: Because there's a difference between learning something and getting an answer. Teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: @Paul: So those asking questions not assigned by a teacher merely get answers and learning is reserved for others?

Comment: Of course not. This is much discussed here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and I don't really have anything to add to that.

Comment: @Paul: The top voted answer there says "the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged," and links to the official meta-tag policy on the SO blog.

Comment: yes, but after something that says "Admit that the question is homework. Trying to hide it will just get the question closed faster. Do this by mentioning that it is homework in the question text;"! My point was that knowing it is homework does matter

Comment: ofcource its in #define.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is a hex value, 0x12345678, written as binary, and annotated with some bit positions:

```
|31           24|23           16|15            8|7         bit 0|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0|0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0|0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0|0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

...and here is 0x000000FF:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

So a bitwise AND selects just the bottom 8 bits of the original value:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

...and shifting it left by 24 bits moves it from the bottom 8 bits to the top:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
|0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0|
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

...which is 0x78000000 in hex.

The other parts work on the remaining 8-bit portions of the input:

```
  0x12345678
& 0x000000FF
  ----------
  0x00000078 << 24 = 0x78000000       (as shown above)

  0x12345678
& 0x0000FF00
  ----------
  0x00005600 <<  8 = 0x00560000

  0x12345678
& 0x00FF0000
  ----------
  0x00340000 >>  8 = 0x00003400

  0x12345678
& 0x00000000
  ----------
  0x12000000 >> 24 = 0x00000012

                   | ----------
                     0x78563412
```

so the overall effect is to consider the 32-bit value `ldata` as a sequence of four 8-bit bytes, and reverse their order.

Comment: So, basically, this is a 32-bit-value Little-Endian <=> Big Endian converter.

Comment: great thanks what will be the purpose of it by little Endian and big Endian

Comment: "Machine epsilon" is a numerical property of a floating-point representation, and has nothing to do with bit shifting, masking, or endianness.  I have no idea what you mean by "WKB".

Comment: wkb means wel known binary representation.. used for storing the spatail data in binary form.

Comment: so i thought that may be its sued for this purpose

Comment: The point I don’t understand is why `AND`ing with `FF` is needed at all steps. Doesn’t the calculation result in same without it ?

Answer (score 5):

This kind of code tends to be used to swap things between [big endian and little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format. There is also a little trick that will convert a word in some known format (lets say, little endian) into whatever endianness the current machine happens to be, and vice versa. That would go something like this:

```
unsigned long littleEndian;
unsigned char* littleBytes = &littleEndian;
unsigned long result = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    result += unsigned long(littleBytes[i]) << (8 * i);
```

This works (assuming I haven't messed it up) because regardless of how bytes are actually stored, shift left is guaranteed to shift towards more significant bits. Converting to a char* allows you to access the bytes in the order they are actually stored in memory. Using this trick you don't need to detect the machine endianness to read/write stuff in a known format. Admittedly you could also just use the standard functions (hton etc.) :P

(Note: You have to be a little careful and cast the char before shifting, otherwise it just overflows all over your shoes. Also, += isn't the only option, |= would probably make more sense but might be less clear if you aren't used to it, I'm not sure)

Comment: can you tell me about significant number.. i have read about double and float  point representation but i did not understand significant.

Comment: is this relate to machine epsilon?

Comment: by significant I just mean worth more, or bigger. If I have the number 123, the most significant digit is the 1, because it is "worth" 100. Same idea for bits and bytes in a number. Some machine store bytes in a different order, so the most significant byte of a number might be stored at the first memory address, or it might be the last.

Comment: WHAT IS MACHINE EPSILON. IS THIS RELATE TO THAT OR wWKB

Comment: oh i see OK can you tell me about significantly digit in float point representation in binary.. like float take 4B in memory and its represented as 0sign bit,8bit exponent and all others are fraction.. what will be signification digit here for storing a number.

Comment: and byte order is used for WKB or machine epsilon?

Comment: i mean when we need to use it? and why??

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the `0x000000FF` as a bitmask, i.e. where it's 1 the value of `ldata` will be taken and where it's 0  - 0 will be taken.

In order to understand the bitmask u need to convert it to binary, with hex it's very easy, every hex number is 4 binary digits, i.e.:

hex 0 = binary 0000
hex 1 = binary 0001
and so on.

Now to shifts: notice that the shift takes some data from the source, 8 bits exactly, and moves it to another location in the destination.

Now note that there's `|` i.e. OR operation on all the bitmask AND operations, i.e. zeroes will stay zeroes and in case there's '1' the result will contain one.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say data is a 32 bit number represented as 0x12345678 (each number is 4 bits in hex)

Data & 0x000000FF means keep only the last 8 bits (called a bit mask)
= 0x00000078

The << 24 means move this value to the left 24 bits (78 starts at position 24 [0 index])
= 0x78000000

The | means logical or which in this case will just be an addition

Final result = 0x78563412

Read on logical manipulations

Comment: In this case, it's to swap endianess of a 32 bit number. I wouldn't write this as a #define but a function instead. Here's a good read and why you need these types of functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness