# converting bytes to integers in a bytebuffer

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I have found this piece of code that I have posted below that should 
 convert bytes to integers, however I do not fully understand how this piece
 of code works in java. I believe bytebuffer is used in this case in a full 
piece of code as it is just a part I am struggling to understand.

```
public static byte[] intToBytes(int i) {
    return new byte[] {
        (byte) ((i & 0x000000FF) >> 0),
        (byte) ((i & 0x0000FF00) >> 8),           
        (byte) ((i & 0x00FF0000) >> 16),
        (byte) ((i & 0xFF000000) >> 24)
    };
```

Comment: That doesn't convert byte to integers it converts an integer to bytes. Specifically 4 bytes. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4058656/4417924

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int bytesToInt(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
}
```

Comment: It shifts the bytes so more significant bits will become less significant bits.